# what does add_dependence() do?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am a new learner of ROS.

Recently, I created a package called beginner.

Then I did the test called WritingPublisherSubscriber.

When I added context into CMakeLists.txt, I copied directly

```
add_dependencies(listener beginner_turorials_generate_message_cpp)
add_dependencies(talker beginner_turorials_generate_message_cpp)
```

rather than

```
add_dependencies(listener beginner_generate_message_cpp)
add_dependencies(talker beginner_generate_message_cpp)
```

After I compiled it, the program ran nornally.

I was very confused about it.

Please tell me what happened inside

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269990/what-does-add_dependence()-do?/) by [roovie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31755/roovie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-31**:
Welcome. I edited your question for you, but in the future please use the `101010` button to format your text to make it more readable. You may find that you get more attention with well-formatted questions.

**Comment by [roovie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31755/roovie/) on 2017-08-31**:
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html)'s documentation:

> Add a dependency between top-level
> targets.
>
> `add_dependencies(<target> [<target-dependency>]...)`
>
> Make a
> top-level  depend on other
> top-level targets to ensure that they
> build before  does. A
> top-level target is one created by
> ADD_EXECUTABLE, ADD_LIBRARY, or
> ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET. Dependencies added
> to an IMPORTED target are followed
> transitively in its place since the
> target itself does not build.
>
> See the DEPENDS option of
> ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET and
> ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND for adding
> file-level dependencies in custom
> rules. See the OBJECT_DEPENDS option
> in SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES to add
> file-level dependencies to object
> files.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
And just to note: @roovie: this is not something we made up in ROS, but is a piece of CMake infrastructure to allow you to express dependencies between (make) targets.